# Find names with a given first name

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.5 under miniconda3. In line with the examples given in https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html as in:

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=-)\w+', 'spam-egg')
m.group(0)
'egg'
```

I wanted to find all the names that have the first name as Bob. So, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
import re
names = ['Raman Srinivasan', 'Balaji Srinivasan', 'Bob Stuart', 
         'Divya Srinivasan', 'James Ford', 'Bob Simposon', 'Bob Willis']
starts_with_bob = r'(?<=Bob)\w+'
for i in names:
    found = re.search(starts_with_bob, i)
    print(found.group(0))
```

But, Jupyter threw the error:

```
     5 for i in names:
     6     found = re.search(starts_with_bob, str(i))
---->7     print(found.group(0))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I then tried to remove the raw-text indicator r and changed the search pattern to:

```
starts_with_bob = '(?<=Bob)\w+'
```

which too gave the same error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. Your regex matches things like:

```
BobSmith
BobStamper
BobStevens
```

See? Your regex needs an extra space and start and end anchors:

```
(?<=^Bob )\w+$
```

Alternatively, you can use this regex without a lookbehind:

```
^Bob (\w+)$
```

And get `group(1)`

There is another mistake in your code. When the regex fails to match, `search` returns `None`. You need to check for `None` and only if `found` is not `None`, you print the match:

```
import re
names = ['Raman Srinivasan', 'Balaji Srinivasan', 'Bob Stuart', 
         'Divya Srinivasan', 'James Ford', 'Bob Simposon', 'Bob Willis']
starts_with_bob = r'(?<=^Bob) \w+$'
for i in names:
    found = re.search(starts_with_bob, i)
    if found != None:
        print(found.group(0))
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out my mistake and also to correct my erroneous assumption that space after 'Bob' should be included within brackets like *(?<=Bob )*

Comment: This will also match things like `kjhBob Wills` etc... The clue is `FIRST NAME MUST BE BOB` so you must have a boundary on `\\bBob\\b`

Comment: @Onyambu yeah you are right. I missed that. Edited.

Comment: @Onyambu the sample data that OP showed in the question does not show that there can be leading or trailing spaces. I assumed some constraints of the input data based on what OP wrote in the question. To me OP just seems to want to learn how to use regex instead of solving a real world problem.

Comment: `^(?<=Bob )\w+$` will never match any string Because there cannot be any `Bob` before the start of a string. You meant to use `(?<=^Bob )\w+$`